# Loop read.csv files containing pattern in file name

Tags: r, loops, read.csv

I created a vector with 30 words, called "club"

```
club <- pixid$ack1
```

Next i want to import 30 csv files. Each filename contains 1 of the words in "club".

```
for (i in club){
DCM.[i] <- read.csv(list.files(pattern = "[i]"))
}
```

However I receive the following error:

> Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument.

How can I read in all of these files containing names from the vector?  I'm hoping this is just a syntax error.

Comment: You don't need `[]`  Perhaps this helps `DCM <- vector("list", length(club)); for(i in seq_along(club)){DCM[[i]] <- read.csv(list.files(pattern = club[i]))}`  assuming that `club` is `character` class

Comment: yes, 'club' is a character.  unfortunately that still give me the: 'Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument' error.

Comment: You may need to provide a small reproducible example.

Comment: Example: `club <- c("ARI","ATL")`

File names:  
`34562_Conversions_ARI_YTD_20170128_060408_521702287.csv`
`6482_Conversions_BAL_YTD_20170128_060612_521699121.csv`

Comment: What do you get when you do `sapply(clubs, function(x) list.files(pattern=x))`

Comment: I get a list of each file containing the pattern from `club`

`$ARI

[1] "6482_Conversions_ARI_YTD_20170128_060408_521702287.csv"

[2] "Conversions_ARI_YTD.zip"

$BAL

[1] "6482_Conversions_BAL_YTD_20170128_060612_521699121.csv"

[2] "Conversions_BAL_YTD.zip" `

Comment: I think that is the error, you have a `list` so, use `read.csv(list.files(pattern=club[i])[[1]])}`

Comment: Also, there is a chance that you may have more than one file for each pattern.  In that case, we need a second loop to read the files separately

Comment: tried that and recieved `Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed`

Yeah, I just moved all of the relevant files to a new directory get that variable issue out of the way.

Comment: Can you please try the code I posted below as a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that there are multiple files for a single `pattern` in the 'club' `vector`.  We loop through the 'club' of patterns, list the files based on that pattern using `list.files` and then loop through the file names, and read it with `read.csv`

```
DCM <- lapply(club, function(x) lapply(list.files(pattern = x), 
               function(x) read.csv(x, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, row.names = NULL)))
```

The above is a nested `list` containing a `list` of `data.frame`s for each pattern provided by the 'club'.

Comment: that did the trick!! thanks for working on this.. saving me mucho tiempo.  I should spend time learning the apply functions